# How can I make this encryptor/decryptor work by using .join .slice or .push?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a encryptor / decryptor (extremely simple), and I need to switch out all "o" for "!", "e" for "#", "t" for "%" and "n" for "&".

First you should write a text, push a button and encrypt it, then a button to decrypt it to it's original input, but I can't seem to get it working. (I'm extremely new to JS).

I am currently doing a for-loop, but if there is any better suggestion I'll try to understand.

```
    function fResult() {

        var deKey = [
            "o",
            "e",
            "t",
            "n"
        ];

        var str = document.getElementById("text").value;

        var enKey = [
            "!",
            "#",
            "%",
            "&"
        ];

        var resultEn = fEncrypted(str, deKey, enKey);

        document.getElementById("writeText").innerHTML= resultEn;

    }

    function fEncrypted(str, deKey, enKey) {

        var resultKey = []
        str = str.split("", str.length);

        for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {

            if (str[i] == "o") {

                str.slice(str[i]);
            }
            if (str[i] == "e") {

                resultKey.push(enKey[1]);
            }
            if (str[i] == "t") {

                resultKey.push(enKey[2]);
            }
            if (str[i] == "n") {

                resultKey.splice(1, 1, (enKey[3]));
            }

            else {
                resultKey.push(str[i]);
            }
```

I figure since I use `if str[i] == "letter"` it should skip the push on `else`, but it just pushes the intended "encryption letter" in front of the original letter.

Comment: can you post what you want to achieve? or some output result for the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like that:

```
    function fEncrypted(str, deKey, enKey) {
      var newStr = str.split('');
      //run through every character in string
      for (var i = 0; i < newStr.length; i++) {
        //run for each character in the encryption values
        for (var j = 0; j < deKey.length; j++){
          if(newStr[i] == deKey[j]) {
            newStr[i] = enKey[j];
            break;
          }
        }
      }
      return newStr.join('');
    }
```

I don't believe this is the most efficient way to do this, though. For instance, for a larger amount of key values to encryption, you could use a hash table, so the code would be something like that:

```
    function fEncrypted(str, deKey, enKey) {
      var newStr = str.split('');

      //setup hash table
      hashtable = {}
      for (var i = 0; i < deKey.length; i++){
        hashtable[deKey[i]]=enKey[i];
      }

      //run through every character in string
      for (var i = 0; i < newStr.length; i++) {
        if ( hashtable[newStr[i]] != undefined ) {
          newStr[i] = hashtable[newStr[i]];
        }
      }
      return newStr.join('');
    }
```

Since you are new to javascript, I think it's valid to point out that for loops are usually made with map, reduce, filter or forEach. I didn't use any of those so the code would be more clear to you.

Comment: Thanks for your comment!

I tried something like this, but it results in only the first occurence being encrypted, the rest is left unchanged.

"break" ends the loop right? I removed the "break", but it didn't help.

Comment: The "break" statement will break only the inner loop. Once you find the matching character there is no reason to keep looking for it on the deKey/enKey arrays. I have tested both functions on node and it works. Can you share your HTML file so I can take a look on it?

Comment: I failed misserably by putting the return above the "{", making it a part of the loop. It's resolved! Thank you so much! I really look forward to learning JS!

Answer (score 0):

The else only applies to the last if. To do what you are asking about the else you need to use else if on all but the first and last block. I am confused why each block is different if they all should do the same thing essentially.

```
        if (str[i] == "o") {

            str.slice(str[i]);
        }
        else if (str[i] == "e") {

            resultKey.push(enKey[1]);
        }
        else if (str[i] == "t") {

            resultKey.push(enKey[2]);
        }
        else if (str[i] == "n") {

            resultKey.splice(1, 1, (enKey[3]));
        }
        else {
            resultKey.push(str[i]);
        }
```

Also, can you just use `replace()`? [It](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) can use a regex with global and case insensitve options to do what you want. The link has an example of this.